# Full width heading over three columns using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to lay out a container in multiple columns, but have one heading span all the columns.

Unfortunately, the `column-span` CSS3 property is not (yet) supported by Firefox, so I'm looking for an alternate implementation that does not use `column-span`, and I thought it should be possible with `flex`.

This is the HTML I have to work with. ***I cannot modify the HTML by wrapping parts of it in sub-containers.*** As such, I'm looking for a CSS solution (or perhaps js).

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>Headline</h2>
  <h3>Item title</h3>
  <p>Nulla eum futurum demonstraverunt possim mazim. Wisi esse in congue littera iusto. Eu diam ea augue vero ii. </p>
  <h3>Item 2 title</h3>
  <p>Aliquam parum nam doming eodem amet. Legere blandit duis nisl in diam. Dignissim dolore dolore vulputate accumsan laoreet.
  </p>
  <h3>Item 3 title</h3>
  <p>Parum erat est quam etiam suscipit. Habent ullamcorper iriure nulla eros lius. Elit etiam gothica demonstraverunt mirum duis. Dolor blandit parum notare soluta aliquam. Consequat iusto suscipit lobortis usus lorem. Quarta tempor typi te modo videntur.
  </p>
  <h3>Item 4 title</h3>
  <p>Eu laoreet decima est est at. Parum anteposuerit notare molestie typi nonummy. Claritatem quod quam dolor saepius qui. Et in processus et tincidunt typi. Cum augue facilisi liber ad doming. Hendrerit eorum per eleifend vero mirum. Decima laoreet nulla dolore tincidunt iusto. Eleifend parum aliquam ut dolore facilisis. Volutpat modo in in zzril nunc. 
  </p>
  <h3>Item 5 title</h3>
  <p>Clari mirum odio qui quam euismod. At fiant tempor zzril in autem. Facit nonummy dignissim eros notare nulla. Exerci qui in zzril ex qui. Dignissim et saepius at anteposuerit hendrerit. Congue videntur congue augue est dynamicus. Imperdiet legunt lorem dolore dolore in. Mazim typi mazim habent volutpat magna. Accumsan habent lobortis hendrerit me lobortis. 
  </p>
  <h3>Item 6 title</h3>
  <p>Sed in claritas dolor eu volutpat. Nostrud insitam magna dolore typi exerci. Esse veniam velit esse esse anteposuerit. 
  </p>
  <h3>Item 7 title</h3>
  <p>Odio iis commodo insitam et nobis. Euismod commodo legere eodem commodo clari. Consectetuer Investigationes eodem quod wisi facit. Nibh id claram iriure praesent qui. Ut non modo zzril claram claram. Et est est wisi typi quinta. 
  </p>    
</div>
```

The following snippet shows the desired output, by using `columns` and `column-span`:

```css
#wrapper {
  columns: 3;
}
h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <h3>Item title</h3>
    <p>Nulla eum futurum demonstraverunt possim mazim. Wisi esse in congue littera iusto. Eu diam ea augue vero ii.</p>
    <h3>Item 2 title</h3>
    <p>Aliquam parum nam doming eodem amet. Legere blandit duis nisl in diam. Dignissim dolore dolore vulputate accumsan laoreet.
    </p>
    <h3>Item 3 title</h3>
    <p>Parum erat est quam etiam suscipit. Habent ullamcorper iriure nulla eros lius. Elit etiam gothica demonstraverunt mirum duis. Dolor blandit parum notare soluta aliquam. Consequat iusto suscipit lobortis usus lorem. Quarta tempor typi te modo videntur.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a codepen with my attempt at using `flex`:  http://codepen.io/fulv/pen/bZOWVY

Again, here is the CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  width: 30%;
}

h3 {
  page-break-after: avoid;
  break-after: avoid;
}

h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

The problem is the `h2` Headline:  I cannot figure out how to make it stretch across the three columns.

A secondary problem is how to make the `h3`s and the following `p`s not break across column boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [flex `order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) can be very handy. No changes to the HTML.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
}
h3 {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
p {
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>Headline</h2>
  <h3>Item title</h3>
  <p>Nulla eum futurum demonstraverunt possim mazim. Wisi esse in congue littera iusto. Eu diam ea augue vero ii.</p>
  <h3>Item 2 title</h3>
  <p>Aliquam parum nam doming eodem amet. Legere blandit duis nisl in diam. Dignissim dolore dolore vulputate accumsan laoreet.
  </p>
  <h3>Item 3 title</h3>
  <p>Parum erat est quam etiam suscipit. Habent ullamcorper iriure nulla eros lius. Elit etiam gothica demonstraverunt mirum duis. Dolor blandit parum notare soluta aliquam. Consequat iusto suscipit lobortis usus lorem. Quarta tempor typi te modo videntur.
  </p>
</div>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKvJvO?editors=1100)

Comment: Sorry, my input html was a bit misleading:  it is not limited to three (or less) h3+p groups, it can have more and not necessarily multiples of 3.  That's why I started with flex-flow: column wrap, because I want the text after the headline to wrap in columns just like a newspaper article.

Comment: That's not reasonably possible in CSS without modifying the HTML. At a minimum, the headline should get its own wrapper.

Comment: How would things change with a wrapper around just the headline?

Comment: I could put a header wrapper around the headline, but I can't put a section wrapper around everything else.